# How to add decryption values for jwt and easyauth for azure functions

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-functions

I have an Azure AD app registration that encrypts the JWT tokens it creates and this works well for API management. i decrypt and validate the token in API management with the following policy:

```
    <validate-jwt header-name="Authorization" failed-validation-httpcode="401">
        <openid-config url="https://login.microsoftonline.com/organizations/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration" />
        <decryption-keys>
            <key certificate-id="jwts" />
        </decryption-keys>
        <audiences>
            <audience>!redacted!</audience>
        </audiences>
        <issuers>
            <issuer>!redacted!</issuer>
        </issuers>
        <required-claims>
            <claim name="roles" match="any">
                <value>Accounts.Read.All</value>
            </claim>
        </required-claims>
    </validate-jwt>
```

however, when I forward the request to the function app with easyauth enabled I get the following error:

```
{
  "code": 401,
  "message": "IDX10609: Decryption failed. No Keys tried: token: '[PII is hidden]'."
}
```

this makes sense because I haven't specified the decryption key anywhere but I can't seem to find the setting for this value anywhere? does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Please check in case if any of the following are causes

- Please check if you have  passed App ID in the allowed audiences  >:
  `api://{Azure Function AD App Id }`.
- Try giving authentication level as anonymous .Also check if function
  key is given if the authentication level is not anonymous in your
  case. [Adding Authentication to Your HTTP Triggered Azure Functions -
  DZone Security](https://dzone.com/articles/adding-authentication-to-your-http-triggered-azure)
- Also after the token is received check its issuer endpoint and see if
  the accesstokenacceptedversion has the same version.
- And check if you need to turn on the system managed identity in apim
  and change the inbound access policy to the same in the apim.

**References:**

1. [Working with Azure Functions and (APIM)
   offering (majorguidancesolutions.com)](https://training.majorguidancesolutions.com/blog/azure-functions-and-apim-1)
2. [Securing your Azure Functions App with API Management - Cloud
   management at your fingertips (mscloud.be)](https://mscloud.be/azure/Securing-your-Azure-Functions-App-with-APIM/)
3. [using-msal-net-to-call-an-azure-function-app-with-easy-auth-enabled](https://aaddevsup.azurewebsites.net/2019/08/using-msal-net-to-call-an-azure-function-app-with-easy-auth-enabled/)

Comment: Thanks for the reply but the flow works for un-encrypted tokens. As soon as I add the encryption settings in AAD, I need to add the decryption key in apim (which works). However apim forwards the encrypted token and I can't add any decryption keys in the easyauth settings (as far as I can see)